# Kendo Grid - sorting by selected column and date

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i use Kendo grid in ASP.NET MVC app. 
I have grid with 6 columns which are sorted by date in default. User can click on header of one of the columns a override default sort and sort by column of his choosing.
What I want to achieve is "second tier sorting". When user sorts by name and there are 10 records with the same name, i want the 10 records to be sorted by date (descending). So far, I haven´t found anyting useful.
Thanks

Comment: Try using an array in the [`sort`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/sort) method, e.g.: `.sort([{ field: "abc", dir: "asc" }, { field: "def", dir: "desc" }]);`

Comment: well, that just sets the default sorting when rendering the grind, right? If an user clicks on column header for custom sorting, the sort metod gets overriden by the user's click